# Ошибка при поднятии автономного бота для Discord

Tags: python, discord

Такая проблема: когда запускаю код через терминал, то всё работает, но когда хочу поднять бота на `Heroku`, то происходит следующая ошибка:

```
2020-07-20T15:06:07.450702+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-07-20T15:06:07.450780+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
2020-07-20T15:06:07.450781+00:00 app[worker.1]:     yield from command.invoke(ctx)
2020-07-20T15:06:07.450785+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 374, in invoke
2020-07-20T15:06:07.450785+00:00 app[worker.1]:     yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
2020-07-20T15:06:07.450815+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 54, in wrapped
2020-07-20T15:06:07.450815+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
2020-07-20T15:06:07.450863+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'delete'
2020-07-20T15:14:55.181076+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in command None
2020-07-20T15:14:55.181168+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "clearqp_admin" is not found
```

Не понимаю в чем ошибка.

Comment: Код точно одинаковый? Если да проверьте что скачаны все нужные библиотеки.

Comment: @merive_ да, код одинаковый, библиотеки стоят все... Мучаюсь уже который день :с